# Missing time class

Tags: r

Below are two columns with what I have and what I want. 
I need to convert the have into want. Essentially, I am creating a 24 hour time sequence.

HAVE
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
141
142
143
144
145
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159

WANT
0:00
0:01
0:02
0:03
0:04
0:05
0:06
0:07
0:08
0:09
0:10
0:11
0:12
0:13
0:14
0:15
0:16
0:17
0:18
0:19
0:20
0:21
0:22
0:23
0:24
0:25
0:26
0:27
0:28
0:29
0:30
0:31
0:32
0:33
0:34
0:35
0:36
0:37
0:38
0:39
0:40
0:41
0:42
0:43
0:44
0:45
0:46
0:47
0:48
0:49
0:50
0:51
0:52
0:53
0:54
0:55
0:56
0:57
0:58
0:59
1:00
1:01
1:02
1:03
1:04
1:05
1:06
1:07
1:08
1:09
1:10
1:11
1:12
1:13
1:14
1:15
1:16
1:17
1:18
1:19
1:20
1:21
1:22
1:23
1:24
1:25
1:26
1:27
1:28
1:29
1:30
1:31
1:32
1:33
1:34
1:35
1:36
1:37
1:38
1:39
1:40
1:41
1:42
1:43
1:44
1:45
1:46
1:47
1:48
1:49
1:50
1:51
1:52
1:53
1:54
1:55
1:56
1:57
1:58
1:59

Comment: What are the rules for conversion?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the package `chron`:

```
install.packages("chron")
```

I reproduced a short version of your data as follows:

```
list1 <- c(0,1,2,3, 68)
```

The code that you should use is the following - replacing the list1 with the name of your list or dataframe column.

```
library(chron)
substr(times((list1%/%60 +  list1%%60 /60)/24), 1, 5)
```